# Accept any number in pacts somethingLike

Tags: php, pact

in my clients pact-contract I have rules like

```
{
   foo: like(1.2)
}
```

What I want to require is that foo is a either a float, or an integer. On the provider side however pact tests fail for integers.

My provider-side (PHP) looks something like this:

```
myApi() {
   return [
      foo => (float) 1 // Returns 1 in PHP, not 1.0
   ];
}
```

Does the provider really need to return `1.0` instead of `1` or is it possible to write the contract in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-ruby/issues/191 (and other related such as https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/issues/94). It should actually now be supported by the framework based on feedback and discussion.

Pact PHP needs to upgrade to the latest of this underlying library (it is an engine used under the hood) and it *should just work*

Answer (score 0):

No its not needed because if you var_dump(foo) the same; then you will find it of type float. If the value contains more precision or value after decimals then it will return that float value but for 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,4.0, 11.0, 123.0 .... i.e. if there are no digits after decimal other than 0 then , it will always output it in single highest number i.e. 1,2, 11, 123

Comment: But the pact-tests fail because it compares the outputted json of the API and differentiates between fixed and float numbers. Thus, the tests fail.